# Structure json inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to do a json structure like this, but with more than 1 items:

```
charge = {
   items: [{
    name: "Product A",
    value: 1000,
    amount: 2
    }]
}
```

I have an `@items` that is `@items.pluck(:name, :price)`
And I'm trying to create my json like this:

```
  charge = {
   items: [{
    @items.each do |item|
     'name:' = item.name,
     'value:' = item.price,
     'amount:' = 2
    end
    }]
}
```

And return this error:

```
SyntaxError in CoursesController#qualquer

syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
'name:' = item.name,
```

How i do this structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things I see wrong.  First, you're using "=" operator to set a Ruby Hash value.  That's not correct, as Ruby hashes use symbols or strings.  So your hash values will need to look like this:

```
{ "may_hash_key" => my.has_value }
```

or

```
{ my_hash_key: my.hash_value }
```

or

```
{ :may_hash_key => my.has_value }
```

Take your pick.

Additionally, if you are rendering JSON from your controller action, you can do something like this:

```
def index
  # presumably some setup code
  charge = {
    items: @items.map do |item| {
      name:   item.name,
      value:  item.price,
      amount: 2
    } end
  }
  render json: charge
end
```

If you are not rendering JSON from your controller action, what you can do is set @charge and interact with it as a Ruby hash in your view instead.